# Converting a pointer-to-member-of-base to a pointer-to-member-of-derived

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

A simplified example from [a recent blog post](https://ibob.github.io/blog/2018/08/18/a-bug-in-the-cpp-standard/):

```
struct B { void f(); };
struct D : B { };

constexpr auto as_d = static_cast<void(D::*)()>(&D::f); // (1)

template <void (D::*)()>
struct X { };

X<as_d> x; // (2)
```

gcc, clang, and MSVC all accept the declaration of `as_d` marked `(1)`. gcc and clang both reject the declaration of `x` marked `(2)`, but MSVC accepts it.

Both gcc's and clang's error messages indicate that they know that `as_d` is a pointer to member of `B`. clang:

> `<source>:9:3`: error: sorry, non-type template argument of pointer-to-member type `void (D::*)()` that refers to member `B::f` of a different class is not supported yet

gcc:

> `<source>:9:7`: error: `void (D::*)(){((void (D::*)())B::f), 0}` is not a valid template argument for type `void (D::*)()`

Who is right? If gcc/clang, what is the rule we're running afoul of? It sure seems like `as_d` is a converted constant expression of type `void (D::*)()` to me...

Comment: The wording of the clang error suggests that “it should be possible, and we know it should, but uh, we couldn't get it working”. Because pointers to base member functions converted to pointers to member functions are pretty tricky at the assembly level.

Comment: [N4268](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html) seems to have allowed such conversions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `X<decltype(as_d)> x;` ?

Comment: @matiu No, because the template parameter of `X` is a "non-type template parameter" (one that accepts a `constexpr` value).

Answer (score 6):

Well, this ended up being pretty interesting. As far as the language is concerned, the program is valid - `as_d` does meet the requirement for being a valid non-type template argument (it is a converted constant expression of the right type).

However, the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) apparently [does not specify a mangling](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/__QDbLgpFik/SyIbTwclAQAJ) for this situation (that is, having a non-type template argument whose type is a pointer-to-member-to-derived but whose value is a pointer-to-member-to-base). Compilers targeting that ABI (i.e. clang and gcc), as a result, can't accept this code. This explains why clang's error is "sorry, not yet" rather than "no, bad!"

On the other hand, other ABIs have no such mangling problem, and so MSVC and ICC are both able to compile the program just fine.

Comment: Is not it more a hack of a defect introduced in C++17? Because in C++14, a template argument of pointer-to-member type had to be `&T::name expression`, [C++14/\[temp.arg.nontype\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.arg.nontype#1.6): *A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of: [...] a pointer to member expressed as described in [expr.unary.op];[...]*. This restriction has been removed in C++17 and now we have an inconsistent behavior, `X<&D::f>` is ill-formed but not `X<as_d>`.

Comment: I suppose non-type template arguments of pointer-to-member-function type could be mangled as a character identifying whether the function is virtual, followed by a name and this-offset for non-virtual functions, or a vtable-offset and this-offset for virtual functions. Though that would be a breaking ABI change, and I don't know how often compiler vendors are willing to do that.